# How can I translate resources fields in React-admin

Tags: internationalization, react-admin

I tried to make the following file:

```
// i18n.ts
const domainMessages = {
   fa: {
      resources: {
         members: {
            name: "ﺎﻌﺿﺍﺀ",
            fields: {
               email: "ﭗﺴﺗ ﺎﻠﮑﺗﺭﻮﻨﯿﮑﯾ",
               first_name: "ﺎﺴﻣ"
            }  
         }  
      }  
   }  
}; 

export default domainMessages;
```

And defined i18nProvider as:

```
mport domainMessages from './i18n';

const messages = {
    'fa': { ...farsiMessages, ...domainMessages}
};

const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(locale => messages[locale], 'fa');


export const SiteAdmin = () => (
<Admin
    theme={myTheme}
    layout={MyLayout}
    loginPage={LoginPage}
    i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    authProvider={authProvider}>
  <Resource name="members"
    options={{ label: 'ﺎﻌﺿﺍﺀ' }}
    list={ListGuesser}
    edit={EditGuesser}
    show={ShowGuesser} />

...
```

However when I click on `members` resources at `http://localhost:5173/members/3`, it shows English field labels. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using `domainMessages.fa` as follows:

```
const messages = {
    'fa': { ...farsiMessages, ...domainMessages.fa}
};
```